# Prevent Chrome from downloading .log files on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome

For some reason Chrome suddenly started to download .log files, instead of displaying them. Any idea how I can set it to display the .log files as text?

Answer (score 0):

If the log files are indeed plain text, you can force the browser to display them as such by prepending the URLs to the logs with `view-source:`.

This technically works with any link pointing to any type of file, but binary files would print garbage to the tab.

Comment: Seems like a nice hack, but it won't work. Nothing happens. It stays on the same page. Apparently you can't view source, because the browser refuses to load the file